# How to test if a matrix is a rotation matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, rotational-matrices

I have a task to check if a matrix is a rotation matrix, I write code as follow:

```
import numpy as np    

def isRotationMatrix(R):
    # some code here
    # return True or False

R = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
])
print(isRotationMatrix(R))  # Should be True
R = np.array([
    [-1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
])
print(isRotationMatrix(R))  # Should be False
```

I don't know how to implement the function `isRotationMatrix`.

---

My naive implement, it only works for a 3x3 matrix:

```
def isRotationMatrix(R_3x3):
    should_be_norm_one = np.allclose(np.linalg.norm(R_3x3, axis=0), np.ones(shape=3))
    x = R_3x3[:, 0].ravel()
    y = R_3x3[:, 1].ravel()
    z = R_3x3[:, 2].ravel()
    should_be_perpendicular = \
        np.allclose(np.cross(x, y), z) \
        and np.allclose(np.cross(y, z), x) \
        and np.allclose(np.cross(z, x), y)
    return should_be_perpendicular and should_be_norm_one
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but while your questions title is clear, your content of "I looked and found nothing, please and thank you" does not constitute a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation matrix is a [orthonormal matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalMatrix.html) and its determinant should be 1.
My implement:

```
import numpy as np


def isRotationMatrix(R):
    # square matrix test
    if R.ndim != 2 or R.shape[0] != R.shape[1]:
        return False
    should_be_identity = np.allclose(R.dot(R.T), np.identity(R.shape[0], np.float))
    should_be_one = np.allclose(np.linalg.det(R), 1)
    return should_be_identity and should_be_one


if __name__ == '__main__':
    R = np.array([
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
    ])
    print(isRotationMatrix(R))  # True
    R = np.array([
        [-1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
    ])
    print(isRotationMatrix(R))  # True
    print(isRotationMatrix(np.zeros((3, 2))))  # False
```

Comment: Might want to consider that `isRotationMatrix(np.zeros((3, 2)))` should return false, rather than errorring.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for your advice, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022682/how-do-i-prove-that-a-matrix-is-a-rotation-matrix?newreg=fe86d105e3364c76a24545e8082fac59) definition of rotation matrix. A rotation matrix should satisfy the conditions `M (M^T) = (M^T) M = I` and `det(M) = 1`. Here `M^T` denotes transpose of `M`, `I` denotes identity matrix and `det(M)` represents determinant of matrix `M`.

You can use the following python code to check if the matrix is a rotation matrix.

```
import numpy as np

''' I have chosen `M` as an example. Feel free to put in your own matrix.'''
M = np.array([[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]) 

def isRotationMatrix(M):
    tag = False
    I = np.identity(M.shape[0])
    if np.all((np.matmul(M, M.T)) == I) and (np.linalg.det(M)==1): tag = True
    return tag    

if(isRotationMatrix(M)): print 'M is a rotation matrix.'
else: print 'M is not a rotation matrix.'
```

Comment: If the matrix is square, could the conditions be simplified to `M(M^T) = I` and `det(M) = I`?

Comment: @MadLee : Yes, if the matrix is square the conditions can be simplified to `M (M^T) = I` and `det(M) = I`. =)

Comment: FYI, sometimes `np.linalg.det(M)==1.0` doesn't work because of the floating point error.

Comment: @MadLee : Try using `np.linalg.det(M)==1` . I changed the post.

Comment: I think you mean `\det(M)=1`, right? `I` is usually the identity matrix, and does not result from a determinant calculation. Besides, this is only true if `M` describes a proper rotation; it can also describe an [improper rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_rotation), and then `det(M)=−1`.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye : Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the text post to now say `det(M)=1`.